# How do I remove content padding from TextField?

Tags: flutter, textfield, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and I am creating login form, for that I have used TextField  and added prefix icon but I am getting some extra spaces in between textfields (user id and pin) and before the prefix icon. I have also tried InputDecorationTheme but it didn't work.

Please let me know how can I remove or reduce the space.??

Below is my code:

```
TextField(
  maxLength: 8,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: hint,
    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
    prefixIcon: Icon(icon),
    counterText: '',
  ),
)
```

[image: x]

Comment: Did you found the solution?

Comment: @BrindaRathod Just in case you still want to know. I happened to experience the same problem and have a kind of solid solution for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/60018290/12402503

Comment: For those coming to this question after Flutter SDK 1.17.5 see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63160454/6732069

Answer (score 128):

Update (August 2022): still the same as of flutter 3.0.5
Update (April 2021): still work in flutter 2.0.4

As of flutter 1.17.5 (and still the same in 2.X) to completely remove or manipulate the padding manually, first you must set `isDense: true` and then you can adjust the `contentPadding` as you wanted or apply padding on the parent widget instead.

```dart
// using theme
ThemeData(
  inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
     isDense: true,// this will remove the default content padding
     // now you can customize it here or add padding widget
     contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
     ...
  ),
)

// per widget
TextField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(
     isDense: true,
     contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
     ...
   ),
)
```

As mentioned in the comment by [Ataberk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4857232/ataberk) you can also use `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero`

```dart
TextField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(
     isDense: true,
     contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
     ...
   ),
)
```

Comment: why doesnt EdgeSymmetric.zero seem to not work

Comment: TextField has not an `inputDecorationTheme` attribute.

Comment: ```The named parameter 'inputDecorationTheme' isn't defined.``` How is this upvoted?

Comment: `isDense: true` combined with `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero` makes the textfield smallest possible.

Answer (score 40):

You can use `contentPadding` of InputDecoration. 
Here is sample code

```
TextField(
   maxLines: 8,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
      labelText: 'Description',
      labelStyle: txtHintStyle,
   )
 )
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i want to remove additional spaces before prefix icon

Comment: That did exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Zubair Rehman do you find the method to remove the left padding of suffixIcon?

Comment: Actually, have a look a this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63160454/706387) - you need `isDense: true` to remove additional vertical space in TextField

Comment: in my case setting isDense to true worked

Answer (score 27):

I was able to easily achieve that by adding prefix constraints to the prefixIcon and wrapping the prefixIcon with padding like this

```
      TextFormField(
         enabled: true,
         decoration: InputDecoration(
         prefixIconConstraints:BoxConstraints(minWidth: 23, maxHeight: 20),
         prefixIcon: Padding(
                       padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                       child: Icon(
                                Icons.email,
                                color: clockColor,
                               ),
                        ),
         hintText:"Email Address"
         hintStyle:TextStyle(color: hintColor, fontSize: 14),
       ),
    ),
```

heres the output,hope this helps

[image]

Answer (score 18):

I come a bit late, but the only thing you have to do is to use negative padding :

```dart
TextField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: -5),
      labelText: 'Description',
   )
 )
```

Comment: It's working, but need to use `EdgeInsets.all(your_value)`

Comment: It worked here! Jesus, may this always work! I'm using contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: -26)

Answer (score 14):

By applying minus padding by using

```
transform: Matrix4.translationValues(-10.0, 0.0, 0.0),
```

put above line inside the  icon container

```
TextFormField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17),
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: Container(
                transform: Matrix4.translationValues(-10.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.vpn_key,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              labelText: "Enter Password",
              labelStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        ),
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this hack by reducing height of `TextField`

```
SizedBox(
  height: 44, // set this
  child: TextField(),
)
```

Answer (score 4):

That prefixIcon has already contained the padding of 12.0 according to documentation.
So you don't need to provide extra padding.

See this below explanation & code which you can find in input_decorator.dart.

> The prefix icon is constrained with a minimum size of 48px by 48px,
>   but can be expanded beyond that. Anything larger than 24px will
>   require additional padding to ensure it matches the material spec of
>   12px padding between the left edge of the input and leading edge of
>   the prefix icon. To pad the leading edge of the prefix icon:

```
prefixIcon: Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 12.0),
     child: myIcon, // icon is 48px widget.
)
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: thanks for your reply @dhuma, but i want to remove padding not to add more padding :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
TextField(
   maxLines: 1,
   decoration: InputDecoration(contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: -10.0))
 )
```

Answer (score 4):

```
TextField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(
      isDense: true, //Set this to true
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
      hintText: 'Description',
   )
 )
```

Setting `isDense: true` will give you full control of setting the `contentPadding`. Make sure to set the `EdgeInsets.` as your need.

Answer (score 4):

> remove prefixIcon
>
> [image: add icon and follwong two line]

```
Row(
  children: [
    //add icon  
    Icon(Icons.person,color: Colors.grey,),
    Flexible(
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration:  InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: 'User Id',
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),//add content padding
          isDense: true,//add isDense
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
//add some space between two row
SizedBox(height: 10,),
Row(
  children: [
    Icon(Icons.lock,color: Colors.grey,),
    Flexible(
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration:  InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: 'Pin',
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          isDense: true,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 3):

I have try many ways but only worked fine for me.
If you want to remove the left padding of Prefix icon, Give `prefixIconConstraints:BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 20)` to **InpuDecoration** .

```
TextField(
      autocorrect: false,
      textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
      onSubmitted: (value) {
        getXHelper.textFieldSubmit(value, type);
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        isDense: true,
        prefixIconConstraints:BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 20) ,
        hintText: placeHolder,
        prefixIcon: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, right: 5, bottom: 0),
          child: Icon(
            icon,
            size: 20,
          ),
        ),
        suffixIcon: type == TextFieldType.password ? passShowButton : null,
      ),
      controller: controller,
      cursorColor: Colors.black,
      style:
          TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontFamily: AppFontFamily.fontFamily),
    );
```

[Please check the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDVqK.png)

Comment: This is the actual solution which works fine, Thank you for saving my day.

Answer (score 2):

replace prefixIcon-> prefix

```
 TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefix:Icon(
                  Icons.perm_identity_outlined,
                  color: AppColors.primary,
                ),
                labelText:'UserName'
              ),
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set This value for TextFeild

```
   decoration: InputDecoration(
   isDense: true,
   contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
   ...
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to achieve something similar but could not find perfect solution. Came up with and work around using Stack widget.

```
Widget _username(context){
  return SizedBox(
    height: 35,
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.mail,
            size: 20,
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          ),
        ),
        TextField(
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white
          ),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 11.0, horizontal: 33.0),
            hasFloatingPlaceholder: false,
            labelText: 'Username',
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white
            ),
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                )
            ),
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]
    ),
  );
}
```

SizedBox is used to control the vertical padding. For horizontal padding, Icon and TextField are stacked. This results overlapped TextField's label above Icon so contentPadding property is used to move the label to the right. With this I achieved following look.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use

```
buildCounter: (BuildContext context, {int? currentLength, int? maxLength, bool? isFocused}) => null,
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it solved this issue:

```
Widget buildCustomPrefixIcon(IconData iconData) {
  return Container(
    width: 0,
    alignment: Alignment(-0.99, 0.0),
    child: Icon(
      iconData,
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

```
TextFormField(
  controller: _textEditConPassword,
  focusNode: _passwordFocus,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  validator: _validatePassword,
  style: getStyleText(context),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      isDense: true,
      //to reduce the size of icon, use if you want. I used, because my custom font icon is big
      labelText: AppConstants.PASSWORD,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
      //to make the base line of icon & text in same
      labelStyle: getLabelStyleText(context),
      prefixIcon: buildCustomPrefixIcon(AppCustomIcon.icon_pwd_key)),
)
```