# TextInput in TextFormField Get Bottom Padded If suffixIcon or prefixIcon Property of InputDecoration is Used

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Top picture:**
Normal good looking TextFormField without supplying any `Widget` for `suffixIcon`

**Bottom picture:**
Suppyling `Icon Widget` for `suffixIcon` makes the Text input floating unnecessarily

Any idea what's causing this?

**Code:**
It's a plain TextFormField with `suffixIcon`

```
   TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
      )
    )
```

[image]

Comment: please post your `TextField` code

Comment: @JohnJoe I have added it. It's a plain TextFormField

Comment: you should post it as answer then mark it as correct answer.

Comment: we can answer our own question and mark it as correct? I didn't know that. Oh there's a 2 days delay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Current solution:**

```
TextFormField(
   textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0, right: 12.0),
         child: Icon(Icons.search)
      ),
   ),
)
```

**The documentation:**

```
prefixIcon: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 12.0),
  child: myIcon, // myIcon is a 48px-wide widget.
)
```

Because apparently according to the documentation, the `prefixIcon` and `suffixIcon` are wrapped in `Padding Widget` with value of 12. So to make it back to the original position, we can just wrap it in opposite direction `Padding`, in this case `top` and `right` because I'm using `prefixIcon`. If you use suffixIcon, wrap it with `top` and `left`. And the last thing, to make the Text input not floating (get bottom padded), I add this `textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom`

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it did the trick and it makes totally sense to do it in this way!

Answer (score 1):

This may not the best approach, but it works. You can wrap `TextFormField` with a `Container`. This can make the text and icon in same row.

```
  Padding(
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: Container(
              height: 25,
              child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              ))))
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I can't mark this as a correct answer because it doesn't do the trick for me but at least it gives me an idea how to achieve what I want. I edited my post for the solution I find